# VBA code for copy until last row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How can I modify

```
XLApp.Range("A1:K1" & LastRow).Copy
```

if I want to copy the A1:K1 untill the last row there is data in one of the cells in the selected area . Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Finding Last Used cell In VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 1):

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

will give you the last row in column no 1 ("A"). For last row in column k, you need to use 11 in place of 1.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows a generic way to do that:

```
Range(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)), Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))).Rows.Count
```

you can change the A1 reference to other if you want. The codes copy a range the starts from A1 to right and from right to down.